# Http Request is getting executed multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, axios

When I try to execute the following react code, the axios.get() executed multiple times.
I have attached the screenshot of the log. [Console Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkaus.jpg).
Can anyone please help me regarding this.

```
const CaskList = () =>{

    const [casklist,getCaskList] = useState('');
    const [searchCaskName, getCaskForSearch] = useState('');
    const [searchResultCaskName, setSearchResultCaskName] = useState('');

    const getCaskForSearchFromInput = (event) =>{
        console.log(event.target.value);
        getCaskForSearch(event.target.value);
    };

    useEffect(()=>{
        const func = async() =>{
            const resultCasks = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/getAllApps');
            const actualData = resultCasks.data;
            console.log("**********************" + actualData);
            getCaskList(actualData);
        }
        func();
    })

    const caskToBeRendered = [];
    for(let i=0;i<casklist.length;i++){
        caskToBeRendered.push(<Cask allCasks={casklist[i]} >);
    };
    const options = {
        includeScore: false,
        findAllMatches : true,
        threshold : 0.3
      };

      const fuse = new Fuse(casklist,options);
      const result = fuse.search(searchCaskName);
      setSearchResultCaskName(result);

    return (
        <div>
            {caskToBeRendered}
        </div>
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass a second argument to hook useEffect. [You can read about that](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect)

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and
> unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This
> tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props
> or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special
> case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always
> works.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const func = async() =>{
        const resultCasks = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/getAllApps');
        const actualData = resultCasks.data;
        getCaskList(actualData);
    }
    func();
},[])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a empty dependency array.

If you want to fire `useEffect` once on initial mount only. Like

```
useEffect(() => {
  //your code goes here
}, []);
```

If you want `useEffect` to fire on initial mount and every re-render, you don't pass any dependency array. Like

```
useEffect(() => {
  //your code goes here
});
```